# Mongodb get count of specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I get the count of sub document greater than a specific date.
Suppose I've the following model, I wanted to get the count of chats which is greater than a specific date.

```
model = {
"chats" : [ 
    {
        "comment" : "hi",
        "_id" : ObjectId("576a2107aa7940f029ce6547"),
        "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-06-22T05:24:23.422Z")
    }, 
    {
        "comment" : "asdasdsa",
        "_id" : ObjectId("576a2367aa7940f029ce6548"),
        "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-06-22T05:34:31.628Z")
    }, 
    {
        "comment" : "dsadasd",
        "_id" : ObjectId("576a2369aa7940f029ce6549"),
        "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-06-22T05:34:33.354Z")
    }, 
],}
```

I've already tried with

```
             Model.count({
                 $and: [
                     { 'chats.createdDateTime': {$lt: '2016-06-22T10:03:21.879Z' } }, { '_id':messages[index]._id  }
                 ]
             })
```

also tried some other similar ways. 
can anyone help me ?

if possible please suggest with out using aggregate framework.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do without aggregate.

Comment: okay, but here I've list of data, and need to count each lists chat after the specific date. can u suggest a way.

Comment: What is the version of mongodb you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Data` instead of `String`:

```
Model.count({
             $and: [
                 { 'chats.createdDateTime': {$lt: new Date() } }, 
                 { '_id':messages[index]._id  }
             ]
         })
```

Comment: What is `new Data()`?

Comment: Sorry I'm mistyped, I mean `new Date()`.

Comment: This won't help solving the issue mentioned in the question I think. It will project all the objects of `chats` array, instead of projecting only the objects, which matches the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay to use aggreagte, following query may help you:-

```
var date = '2016-06-22T10:03:21.879Z',

db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
    "$match": {
        "chats.createdDateTime": { "$gt": date}
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "chats": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$chats",
                "as": "o",
                "cond": {  
                     "$gt": [ "$$o.createdDateTime", date ] },             
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

By using the query, `chats` will contain only the objects, that matches the condition provided.

Now you can take the length of `chats` array from each document, which will give you your desired count.

Hope this will help!